# Cannot Convert From String To Microsft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, iformfile

Here I am trying to map model`SliderImage` to viewmodel`SliderImageVM` and return viewmodel.

In `SliderImage` model have

```
public string Image { get; set; }
```

and in `SliderImageVM` viewmodel I have

```
public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
```

Now on converting model to viewmodel I have error saying

> Cannot Convert From String To Microsft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile

Below is my code

```
public SliderImageVM GetSliderBySliderImageVMById(int sliderImageId)
{
    var getSliderImage = uow.Repository<SliderImage>().FindBy(x => x.SliderImageId == sliderImageId).FirstOrDefault();
    SliderImageVM newSliderImgeVM = new SliderImageVM
    {
        SliderImageId = getSliderImage.SliderImageId,

        Photo = getSliderImage.Image, //<------Error in this line
    };
    return newSliderImgeVM;
}
```

Comment: Cloud you please place the error.

Comment: I don't understand your reason for doing so.

Comment: What does the "string" contain?

Comment: I'd like to confirm these information with you: 1) does the `Image` property of `SliderImage` model is used for maintaining file path (or name)?  2) and do you want to assign valid value to `Photo` property of your viewmodel `SliderImageVM` based on retrieved file path/name?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot Convert From String To Microsft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile

If you'd like to assign valid value to `Photo` property of your viewmodel `SliderImageVM` based on retrieved file path/name via `getSliderImage.Image`, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
var getSliderImage = uow.Repository<SliderImage>().FindBy(x => x.SliderImageId == sliderImageId).FirstOrDefault();

// get the file path based on getSliderImage.Image

using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead($"{filepath}"))
{
    SliderImageVM newSliderImgeVM = new SliderImageVM
    {
        SliderImageId = getSliderImage.SliderImageId,

        Photo = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
    };

    // ...
    // code logic here
    // ...
}
```